# Why does Uniform Distributions have no outliers?

Tags: probability, distributions, descriptive-statistics, outliers, kurtosis

I was reading about the relation between Kurtosis and Outliers on Wiki and got across a line 'An example of a platykurtic distribution is the uniform distribution, which does not produce outliers' [here]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis
I mean it would also have some µ ± 2σ cut in probability density curve, then how can U.D not have outliers?

Comment: What would be an unusual value within uniform range of support?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you elaborate more, please?

Comment: +1. Wikipedia is wrong here.  The intended meaning is that $\mu\pm 2\sigma$ lies outside the support of the distribution--but actual *random samples* from a uniform distribution can indeed have outliers.

Comment: Ah! Got it. But how  μ±2σ lies outside the support of the Uniform Distribution?

Comment: For a uniform distribution on an interval of length $L,$ the mean ($\mu$) is in the middle of the interval and the standard deviation $\sigma$ is $L$ times $\sqrt{1/12}\approx  0.29.$  Thus, when you move $2\sigma L\approx 0.58L$ to either side of $\mu,$ you go beyond the endpoints, which are only $L/2 = 0.50L$ away from the middle.  The probability of observing any value beyond the endpoints of the interval is, of course, zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the uniform distribution.  Here is some R code, stuff after a # is a comment:

> set.seed(1234)
>
> random <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 10)
>
> sd(random) mean(random) + 2*sd(random)  #10.89 mean(random) -
>   2*sd(random)  #-0.75

So, we see that there is no value in this data set that is more than 2 SD above the mean or less than 2 SD below.

This is true even for much larger N.

For a Normal distribution with large N, some values will be outside the 2 SD range, but these are *not* outliers. An outlier is an unexpected value. If we have a Normal distribution with a large N, then we *expect* some values to be beyond 2 SD. Indeed, for a perfectly Normal distribution, about 5% of the values will be outside this range.  Thus

> set.seed(1234)
>
> random <- rnorm(100000, 0, 1)
>
> sd(random) sum(random > mean(random) + 2*sd(random))  #2389 sum(random
>   < mean(random) - 2*sd(random))  #2235

and we even expect (and get) some beyond 3 SD:

> sum(random > mean(random) + 3*sd(random))  #143 sum(random <
>   mean(random) - 3*sd(random))  #127

The 2 SD rule worked okay as a rule of thumb in the old days, when "big data" meant a few thousand cases.

Comment: This helped a lot. So, what is the best way to identify the outliers in a large dataset according to you?

Comment: There is no one "best way". Identifying outliers requires substantive expertise. You can identify points that merit thought in various graphically ways, at least when the number of dimensions is small.

Comment: who is "merit" ? Didn't get your line "You can identify points that merit thought in various graphically ways"

Comment: "merit" in this context means "these points are worth looking at".